# Select distinct on multiple columns simultaneously, and keep one column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

For a table such as this:

```
tblA  

A,B,C  
1,2,t3a  
1,3,d4g  
1,2,b5e  
1,3,s6u
```

I want to produce a table that selects distinct on both A and B simultaneously, and still keep one value of C, like so:

```
tblB  

A,B,C  
1,2,t3a  
1,3,d4g
```

Seems like this would be simple, but not finding it for the life of me.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblA CASCADE;  
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A,B), C  
INTO tblB  
FROM tblA;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
CREATE TABLE tblB AS (
    SELECT A, B, max(C) AS max_of_C FROM tblA GROUP BY A, B
)
```

Comment: That worked!!
Except one small problem - for some reason column C is now named "max". That's super weird... I can of course rename it, but is there a way to prevent this?  

  
Also - what if I want to keep multiple columns, not just C, like what if there was a column D, E, F, that I wanted to keep as well?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prevent this behaviour. If you don't care about the last value, you can use `max` or `min`. If you want to keep specific values you may need more complex a query.

Comment: That's very strange that it would rename the column.
Also, if I needed several columns, you can't keep using "max" and "min" more than once, since you can only specify the column name once.

If you have another option that can add multiple columns and retain column names, then can you add that to your answer? That would be awesome :)

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You must use aliases, I edited the answer to explain this method.

Comment: Unrelated but: the parentheses around the select are not needed (and add useless noise in my opinion).

Answer (score 7):

When you use `DISTINCT ON` you should have `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A,B), C
INTO tblB
FROM tblA
ORDER BY A, B;
```

Comment: Nope, I did try that before, that returns only C, like so:

tblB:

t3a
d4g

Comment: @NitinGadia . . . This should return unique values for pairs of A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view to do the distinct and then join it to the original table to pick one row of column C.  Inserting into the target is left for you to figure out.  Oh, and you could pick up multiple columns from t, not just c - the only thing is that your subquery needs to find a way to limit it to only one row.

```
create table t (a int, b int, c int);

create view tv as select distinct a, b from t;

insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 2, 10);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 2, 20);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 3, 30);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 3, 40);

CREATE TABLE tblB AS (
select tv.a, tv.b, t.c  from tv, t
where tv.a = t.a and tv.b = t.b
/* pick smallest ctid which is a unique row id built into postgres */
and t.ctid = (select min(ctid) from t s where s.a = t.a and s.b = t.b);
)
```

Comment: that looks way more complicated than the other answers, and also requires you to manually enter a lot of values. The table I'm actually using has thousands of rows.

Comment: The other answer is elegant and may suit you.  But what are you talking about re entering values???  This is just test code, you would use your own table and only create a view to do the distinct.

Comment: oh i see haha
yeah, i like the other ones, they are a bit more simple.
thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: No problem, like I said, they were elegant solutions and I wouldn't have bothered answering if I had seen them first.

Answer (score 0):

```
drop table t;
create table t (a int, b int, c int);

insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 2, 3);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 3, 4);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 2, 5);
insert into t (a, b, c) values(1, 3, 6);

select distinct on (a,b) a, b, c
from t;
```

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html): "SELECT DISTINCT eliminates duplicate rows from the result. SELECT DISTINCT ON eliminates rows that match on all the specified expressions."